# HTTP Status 404 - Servlet not found

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a project in Eclipse and trying to call a servlet from the web browser. The image shows the structure of my project. Although I set the `url` in the annotation I still can't get find the resource.

Here is my code:

```
package java.enablingKeyWordSearch;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(asyncSupported = false, name = "HelloServlet", urlPatterns = {"/hello"})
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.write("<h2>Hello Servlet One </h2>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

[image: project hierarchy]

I have tried calling the servlet using the following:
http://localhost:8080/MultiKeywordSearch/hello
http://localhost:8080/MultiKeywordSearch/src/java/enablingKeyWordSearch/hello

... and so on. Yet, I get an HTTP Status 404 Error.

This is the content of my `web.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MultiKeywordSearch</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I am using Apache Tomcat v8.0 if that makes a difference.

**UPDATE: showing source listing in the new screenshot; removed java namespace**
[image: updated src listing]

**EDIT 2.0**
web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MultiKeywordSearch</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>enablingKeyWordSearch.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/multiKeywordSearch</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The `enablingKeyWordSearch.TestServlet.java` file:

```
package enablingKeyWordSearch;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

//@WebServlet(asyncSupported = false, name = "HelloServlet", urlPatterns = {"/hello"})
@WebServlet(name = "HelloServlet", urlPatterns = {"/multiKeywordSearch"})
@MultipartConfig
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.write("<h2>Hello Servlet One </h2>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Still getting a 404 error sadly.

Comment: What's the warning it's showing on the type name? Also, **change your package names so that they do not use a reserved namespace like "java."**

Comment: It just says the serializable class does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long. Fixing the namespace issue now

Comment: fixed namespace issue, did not fix the problem

Comment: Please update your source listing, and if you are using a web.xml file, include its contents.

Comment: @nitind done, see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@WebServlet("/multiKeywordSearch")

@MultipartConfig


and then try this.
http://localhost:8080/MultiKeyewordSearch/multiKeywordSearch
```

Comment: delete your server and add it again. restart it

Comment: use this command and kill any instance of your server sudo kill $(ps -aef | grep java | grep apache | awk '{print $2}')

Comment: did you add your project to resources while selecting tomcat configuration. the tomacat is unable to find that resource (your project)

Comment: yes. moved it to the "Configured" right side before i created it

Comment: i think that problem is in your web.xml file. servlet mappings must be proper

Comment: i have made suggested changes. see EDIT 2.0

Comment: If he's using annotations, he should not use uri mappings in the deployment descriptor.

Comment: you want me to take out servlet-mappings from `web.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>helloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>java.enablingKeyWordSearch.TestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>helloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: i applied these changes and still getting the same error. i updated the namespace of the src, removing java